# Fragment States do not save when device is rotated

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Please have a look at the following code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class InputFragment extends Fragment {


    private SeekBar daysAsCustomerSeek;

    private View view;

    //Following variables will save the application state and load back
    //on resume

    private final String DAYS_AS_CUSTOMER_VALUE_HOLDER = "days as customer value";




    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Intializing instance variables
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input, container,false);



        daysAsCustomerSeek = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.days_as_customer_seekbar);

        //Set default max values
        daysAsCustomerSeek.setMax(210);
        Log.d("MY_TAG", "Re Created");
        return view;

    }

    //This method will save the instances
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle)
    {
          super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceStateBundle);

        savedInstanceStateBundle.putInt(DAYS_AS_CUSTOMER_VALUE_HOLDER, daysAsCustomerSeek.getProgress());

Log.d("SAVE_LOG", "Instances saved");
    }

    //This method will restore the instances
    @Override 
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceStateBundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceStateBundle);

        if(savedInstanceStateBundle!=null)
        {

            daysAsCustomerSeek.setProgress(savedInstanceStateBundle.getInt(DAYS_AS_CUSTOMER_VALUE_HOLDER));

        }
        Log.d("LOAD_LOG", "Instances loaded");
    }

}
```

When the orientation of the phone changed (when some one rotate the device) this code does not restore the saves states. But it does when the back button is pressed. I found why this is happening with Logs.

```
12-23 16:41:36.623: D/SAVE_LOG(13078): Instances saved
12-23 16:41:45.332: D/MY_TAG(13078): Re Created
12-23 16:41:45.332: D/LOAD_LOG(13078): Instances loaded
12-23 16:41:45.352: D/LOAD_LOG(13078): Instances loaded
12-23 16:41:45.842: D/MY_TAG(13078): Re Created
```

As you can see, it calls `onCreateView()` as the very last method. So everything done in `onActivityCreated()` is undone. I tried to solve this by adding the restoring code at the end of  `onCreateView()` but it fails by saying the `Bundle` is `NULL`.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Override `onSaveInstanceState` method to save the states of the progress bar or other widgets you want to save and retrieve them in `onViewCreated` method

Comment: I meant onSAveInstance(). Answer Edited

Comment: use viewCreated method instead of onActivityCreated. Retrieve the bundle values in onViewCreated

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
   savedInstanceStateBundle.putInt(DAYS_AS_CUSTOMER_VALUE_HOLDER, daysAsCustomerSeek.getProgress());
}
```

The Bundle is essentially a way of storing a `NVP ("Name-Value Pair")` map, and it will get passed in to onCreate and also `onActivityCreated()` where you'd extract the values like this:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    daysAsCustomerSeek.setProgress(savedInstanceStateBundle.getInt(DAYS_AS_CUSTOMER_VALUE_HOLDER));

}
```

You'd usually use this technique to store instance values for your application (`selections`, `unsaved` `text`, etc.).

Comment: He is using fragment. onRestoreInstacestate method is applicable for an Activity

Comment: sorry i updated my answer now! thanks for notifying.